# How can I display a PHP foreach loop's answers by AJAX

Tags: customization, loop, ajax

I have a problem in my AJAX request, I'm trying to get values from a foreach cycle, but it returns empty

```
Functions.php file

 function selectEstado(){
 global $wpdb;
 if(isset($_POST["selectVal"])){ 
    $Estado_id = $_POST["selectVal"];
     $Estado = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM cor_municipio INNER JOIN cor_estado ON cor_municipio.estado_id = cor_estado.estado_id WHERE cor_estado.estado_id = $Estado_id;");
    foreach ( $Estado as $row ) {
        $table .="<tr>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_municipio."</td>";
        $table .="<td>".$row->nombre_estado."</td>";
        $table .="</tr>";
    }
        echo $table;
        wp_die(); 
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'selectEstado');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'selectEstado');
```

AJAX ON page-municipio.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function selectRequest(id){ // id of select
    var selectVal = jQuery(id).val(); // currently selected 
    selectVal = selectVal.toString();
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/cors/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",   
        type:"POST", 
        data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: 'selectVal'},
        success:function(data){ 
            alert(data);  
            jQuery("#municipio_result").hide();
            jQuery("#resultado").append(data);
            },
       });  
    }
```

This is how the data arrives

[image: ALERT BY LOCALHOST]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is selecting from the database where `cor_estado.estado_id` equals `$Estado_id = $_POST["selectVal"];`, but in your JavaScript you're not sending an ID as `$_POST["selectVal"]`, you're literally sending the text string `"selectVal"`:

```
data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: 'selectVal'},
```

Change that to this, to send the actual variable value:

```
data:{action:'my_action', selectVal: selectVal},
```

Comment: Man, you are a lifesaver for this beginner, thanks a lot!!